# Change date-time stamp to unix timestamp in Golden Gate

Tags: unix-timestamp, oracle-golden-gate

how do I change the date-time stamp to unix timestamp in Oracle Golden Gate? There is no inbuilt function in Oracle for it and the function that I am writing might cause delays in GG replication. I cannot afford delays, since GG replicates real-time data

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solutions:

- use SQLEXEC and call custom code (stored procedure) that would make the transformation
- write an USER EXIT custom function in C code and call it from GoldenGate

The second solution would be fastest since there is no round trip when SQL code is being called in the database.